# Obtain Solr version and JVM Properties via web API

Tags: api, solr

Is there a way to obtain the version of Solr, and JVM properties such as the Solr home directory, without having to parse HTML?

Hitting this URL, http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ displays the desired values:
[image: Solr Display]
and the desired values can be parsed from the returned HTML:
`xml
<li class="solr solr_spec_version odd" style="display: list-item;">
<dl class="clearfix">
<dt><span>solr-spec</span></dt>
<dd>5.0.0</dd>
</dl></li>`

Is there a more direct way to obtain these values without having to parse HTML?

Answer (score 2):

This information is loaded via ajax from http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system, which returns this information in either XML or JSON format, for example:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <str name="mode">std</str>
    <str name="solr_home">D:\solr\solr-5.0.0\solr-5.0.0\server\solr\</str>
    <lst name="lucene">
        <str name="solr-spec-version">5.0.0</str>
        <str name="solr-impl-version">5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:26:10</str>
        <str name="lucene-spec-version">5.0.0</str>
        <str name="lucene-impl-version">5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03</str>
    </lst>
    ...
```

These values are loaded by the JavaScript file app.js (server\solr-webapp\webapp\js\scripts\app.js)

`var system_url = config.solr_path + '/admin/info/system?wt=json';`

It is rendered in the ouput via index.js (server\solr-webapp\webapp\js\scripts\index.js):

```
      var data = {
        'start_time' : app.dashboard_values['jvm']['jmx']['startTime'],
        'jvm_version' : app.dashboard_values['jvm']['name'] + ' (' + app.dashboard_values['jvm']['version'] + ')',
        'processors' : app.dashboard_values['jvm']['processors'],
        'solr_spec_version' : app.dashboard_values['lucene']['solr-spec-version'] || '-',
        'solr_impl_version' : app.dashboard_values['lucene']['solr-impl-version'] || '-',
        'lucene_spec_version' : app.dashboard_values['lucene']['lucene-spec-version'] || '-',
        'lucene_impl_version' : app.dashboard_values['lucene']['lucene-impl-version'] || '-'
      };

      for( var key in data )
      {                                                        
        var value_element = $( '.' + key + ' dd', this );

        value_element
          .text( data[key].esc() );

        value_element.closest( 'li' )
          .show();
      }
```